# Mysql trailing trim regex cut string

Tags: mysql, regex, trim, trailing

I have rows

`blablabla-blabla-bla-code1236`

`blablabla-blabla-bla-code23`

trying to cut everything after -code

SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '-code*' FROM mycol) FROM mytable;

What should I put after -code to match all -code* variations. Thanks

another example:

blabla-blasomestufftext-bla-code1234

when I do SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '-code1234' FROM mycol) FROM mytable;

it returns what I need blabla-blasomestufftext-bla

Comment: blablabla-xxx-bla-code1236 becomes blablabla-xxx-bla

Comment: will there be only numbers after code?

Answer (score 0):

```
-code[0-9]+
```

This should work for your cause.

or

```
-code.*
```

If there can be other things besides number.

Comment: SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '-code.*' FROM mycol) FROM mytable; returns whole string, it doesnt cut when meets -code***

Comment: same, no changes. returns unchanged string

Comment: @DmitriyK probaly the way you ar applying is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This trick i often use should works.
If you are searching something in the middle of the string, you can split the string using the fixed substring as delimiter and take the first occurance from the left part.

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol,'-code',1) from mytable

Hope it helps